# What does "partitioned" status mean in Adaptec Storage Manager?

Tags: raid, storage

A few months ago I replaced a failed drive in my RAID 1 array. My OS is Windows 8.1 and the controller is (old) Adaptec 1220SA.  For a few months the array was OK.

Now I'm seeing a degraded status on the RAID array again. It shows one of the drives in "partitioned" status. What does this status mean?  Is the drive failed?

Curiously, this is the **new** drive that's shown in this Partitioned state. I guess it's possible for a new drive to fail after a few months, but it seems suspicious.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Adaptec Storage Manager software, that status that you referenced and highlighted does intuitively mean that the drive currently is set up with an active partition table.

You will notice that next to "State" it says "Partitioned", and below that it shows "Partitioned", and next to that, "Yes", meaning the drive is partitioned.

I can tell you with certainty that "Partitioned" does not mean "failed". However, that does not mean that the drive is not failed. What I am saying is that the only information that you can glean from "Partitioned" is that it means that Adaptec is reading that the drive has an active partition table.

Now, you want to know however whether the drive is failed. It is probably not totally failed yet, but what you need to be looking at is that "Degraded" status.

The Degraded status means that I/O errors have been detected on a region of the disk.

A Degraded status will also display if a disk involving a RAID-5 or mirrored volume was physically moved. To correct the problem, you must move all the disks that contain the volume to the new location or return the moved disk or disks to the original location.

However, considering you do not have a RAID-5, my best guess without more data is that you have gotten a defective drive.

Please note that most drives that are defective will usually show errors or fail within the first few months of use. It is likely in this case that you have a defective drive.

You can double check this drive by first removing it from your RAID array (which I strongly recommend if there is a risk it could fail), and run a disk check program to see if indeed your disk is faulty.

One HDD testing program I like is [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html)

If you tested the drive and you are certain it is not faulty, (it probably is), then please come back here and update. Otherwise, I hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not wanting to take the risk of depending on a perhaps-failed drive, I just ordered and installed a new one. (adding extra install steps below to help future readers) Rebuilding the RAID-1 array was easy: I installed the new drive, marked it as a hot spare, and the array immediately started rebuilding itself. Within a few hours the array was back to Optimal status.

Comment: Excellent! So glad I could help. It sounds like indeed the problem was the drive. :)